# Unfortunately "app_name" has stopped

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

Hello I am new in android developping, I made a small test but it's giving me that error :
'Unfortunately android test has stopped'

I sought some similar topics here, but no one resolved my problem, here is my code :

main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkLogin(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString())){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelloActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else{
                    username.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private boolean checkLogin(String u,String p){
        if (u == "hello" && p == "world")
            return true;
        else return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

the main layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.androidtest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="username" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the second acivity

```
package com.androidtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.hello_layout);

    }

}
```

its layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="193dp"
        android:text="Afin akhay lpchiiwr"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally the Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.androidtest.HelloActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanx

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: You need to post the error you are getting. Look up some debugging tool. Eclipse comes with one.

Comment: While it won't cause an error, `if (u == "hello" && p == "world")` is not correct. This compares objects, not contents. To see if two strings are the same use `if (u.equals("hello") && p.equals("world")`.

Comment: logcat is the first place to look for android bugs :) Especially look at the most recent red text when it crashes.

Comment: u=="hello" was not what caused the bug but I rectified it anyway. thanx guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first xml block you've posted looks like it's from the `fragment_main.xml` file. If so, then your problem is that `findViewById()` is looking for Views in the Activity that have been inflated into the Fragment. If you don't need the Fragment, then move that xml to `activity_main.xml` and remove the code for the Fragment. Otherwise, move the View initializations and methods to your Fragment.

And, as Kedarnath points out, you should use the `String.equals()` method to compare Strings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me tell you that you are comparing String in wrong way,

```
private boolean checkLogin(String u,String p)
{
        if (u == "hello" && p == "world")     // Wrong way
            return true;
        else return false;
}
```

You need to compare string in following way,

```
private boolean checkLogin(String u,String p)
{
        if (u.equals("hello") && p.equals("world") )     // Right way
            return true;
        else return false;
}
```